# How do I target next in array in ERB?

Tags: ruby, csv, erb

Ruby noob here. I just want the @next_name in my ERB file to display the next file name in the array. @prev_name works perfectly, but the @next_name field is blank. What am I doing wrong??

```
require 'csv'
require 'erb'

class Thing

def initialize
  @prev_name = prev_name
  @next_name = next_name
end

template = File.read "workstemplate.erb"
erb_template = ERB.new template

array = Array.new

CSV.foreach("works_list.csv", :headers =>true) do |row|
  fileName = row['fileName']
  title = row['title']
  description = row['description']

  description.tr('"', '')

  array << fileName

  array.each_with_index do |a, i|
    if i> 0 && i< array.size
     @prev_name = array[i-1] 
     @next_name = array[i+1]
    else
     @prev_name == 0
     @next_name == 0
    end  
   end

  work_template = erb_template.result(binding)

  Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists? "output"

  filename = "#{fileName}.html"

  File.open(filename,'w') do |file|
    file.puts work_template
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `CSV.foreach`, which fetches a line per cycle; in order to have a value for `@next_name` you should use something that prefetches every CSV line, like f.e. [`CSV.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-read):

```
CSV.read("works_list.csv", :headers =>true).each do |row|
  ...
```

Comment: Try putting the array block outside the CSV.foreach block. That way you can play about with full final array...

Comment: That gets me a 'wrong number of arguments' error :(

Comment: I meant using the arguments like the answer I updated